# How to change the column type in Hue of a hive table?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hue

I'm trying to create a hive table manually, however I want to change the column type of "order" into an array with a structure (orderline).

My current table is as follows:

[image]

I want to have the same type as orders:

[image]

How can I change the type of a column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, could just edit the types through the hive query editor, with simple SQL statements like:

```
ALTER TABLE person CHANGE orders order ARRAY<STRUCT<status:string,creation_date:string,orderlines:array<STRUCT<depature_date:string,return_date : string, travel_days : int, creation_date: string,
                   price : int, booking_class : string, airline_code : string,
                   psg_gender : string, psg_lastname : string, psg_firstname : string, psg_dob : string>>>>
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, you can do this.
step1:

```
create table testing.lz_test_struct
(
  mark struct<math:string,english:string>
)
row format delimited
fields terminated by ','
collection items terminated by '-';
```

step2:

```
hive> desc testing.lz_test_struct;
OK
mark struct<math:string,english:string,address:string,name:string>
```

step3:

```
hive> alter table testing.lz_test_struct change  mark mark struct<math:string,english:string,address:string,name:string,city:string>;
ok
Time taken: 0.467 seconds
```

step4:

```
hive> desc testing.lz_test_struct;
OK
mark                    struct<math:string,english:string,address:string,name:string,city:string>
Time taken: 0.143 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Comment: Please include text instead of linking images